# How to solve "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error?

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have two S3 buckets. one is having image and pdf data (via CloudFront) and second is statically hosted on s3. when i call image from my URL then it  was loaded, but when i call pdf it shows me following error :-->

> "Access to fetch at 'pdf link' from origin 'url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled".

To solve it i setup S3 CORS policy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And i also setup cloudfront with whitelisting "access-control-request-headers", "access-control-request-method", "origin" these errors and choose GET, PUT, OPTIONS as well.

Suggest how i can solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i overcome from this problem. The main issue was the redirecting of protocol from "HTTP to HTTPS".
when i send the request from HTTP then CloudFront redirects it on HTTPS. By this redirection my image was loading but pdf was not, it was fails during redirection.
Then i change my CloudFront's viewer control protocol to HTTPs Only and now it works.
you can also set it to HTTP and HTTPS.